# Is the MLE product of density functions?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Given that
$(\Bbb R_+^n,\mathcal B(\Bbb R_+^n),(\Bbb P_{\vartheta})_{\vartheta \geq0})$ and $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are iid random variables and for $i=1,...,n$ the density
$$f_\vartheta(x)=e^{\vartheta-x}\mathbf{1}_{[\vartheta;\infty)}(x)=\begin{cases} 
     e^{\vartheta-x}  & \text{if $\vartheta \leq x$}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} $$

I want to calculate the MLE for $\vartheta$.

My attempt:

$L(\vartheta|x_i)=\Pi f_\vartheta(x) \mathbf{1}_{[\vartheta;\infty)} = \Pi e^{\vartheta-x_i}\Pi\mathbf{1}_{[\vartheta;\infty)}=\Pi \frac{e^{n\vartheta}}{e^{x_i}}\Pi\mathbf{1}_{[\vartheta;\infty)}=e^{n\vartheta}\frac{1}{e^\sum x_i}\Pi\mathbf{1}_{[\vartheta;\infty)}=e^{n\vartheta}\frac{1}{e^{n\bar x_n}}\Pi\mathbf{1}_{[\vartheta;\infty)}=\Pi\mathbf{1}_{[\vartheta;\infty)}e^{n\vartheta}e^{-n\bar x_n}=\mathbf{1}_{\cap X_i}e^{n\vartheta-n\bar x_n}=\mathbf{1}_{min {Xi}}e^{n\vartheta-n\bar x_n}$

Is this wrong, correct, not enough ? Thx

Comment: That's the likelihood. You should find the maximiser.

Comment: What you have is partially correct.  Your formula for $f_\vartheta$ writes it as the product of 2 factors, but you have ignored one of them.

Comment: Your likelihood is actually $\theta \mapsto \exp\big\{n\theta-n\bar{x}\big\}\cdot 1_{\big[0,\min\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\big]}(\theta) $

Comment: @kimchilover  please comment on my Edition - thank you

Comment: @MatthewH. please comment on my E

Comment: The trick is to identify for which values of $\theta$ your likelihood function vanishes and for which it does not.